# Issue with uninstalling app not deleting data/nomePackageApp folder on external storage

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage

I'm encountering a strange problem when uninstalling my app on Android on some devices.

I've noticed that even though I uninstall the application correctly, on some devices the `data/nomePackageApp` folder on external storage remains intact. This folder can be accessed using the method `getExternalFilesDir(null)` and contains some files that my app uses.

The problem arises when I try to reinstall the app after uninstalling it. It seems that my app doesn't have the necessary permissions to write to some subfolders within `data/nomePackage`.

Seems it has permission of write and execute only on `data/nomePackage` folder given by  `getExternalFilesDir(null)` and not in its subfolders.

This results in malfunctions within the application and renders it unusable.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue and if there's a known solution.